# set a range for an IN statement

Tags: sql-server-2012

Is it possible to set a range of products for use in a Select IN statement
for example can I rewrite the following:

```
Select Country, SUM(POPULATION) as cPopulation
FROM MyTable
WHERE Country IN ('FRANCE', 'GERMANY', 'SPAIN')
```

To

```
DECLARE @Countries nvarchar(max)
SET @Countries = 'FRANCE', 'GERMANY', 'SPAIN'  /*is this possible?*/

Select Country, SUM(POPULATION) as cPopulation
FROM MyTable
WHERE Country IN (@Countries)
```

Is this even possible

Kind Regards

Comment: I found the acceptable format '''FRANCE'', ''GERMANY'', ''SPAIN''' but it does not return anything

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to create a table variable or temp table and do the IN or join or something like that.

You can do

```
Where '/France/Germany/spain/' like '%/'+country+'/%'
```

But performance will suffer as it will do a scan.